# Horizontally/Vertically Straightening a Shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's say I have a shape that I rotated at an awkward angle of let's say 34°. I close the document, return a few hours later, and want to straighten the it back to its original 90° or 0° angle. The problem is I don't remember the angle I originally rotated it at. Shift + Rotating nor resetting its bounding box does the trick. Any shortcuts/options I'm overlooking here? For example how would I rotate this quadrilateral so that it sits horizontally straight and looks like a box.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using smart-guides, it's pretty easy to make a new guide and align your edges to them. Set the center of rotation to intersect the lowest desired edge and a guide, then rotate until both are collateral.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a free plugin from Astute Graphics for just this very situation - http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/subscribe/. As simple as selecting the points on the edge you want to be horizontal, holding shift to constrain the angle and dragging.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation (if any) with the linked product.

Comment: No affiliation whatsoever, I just use it on a regular basis and would recommend it to any Illustrator user.

Comment: Cool. It's not a problem to be affiliated, but on stackexchange it's a good habit to fully disclose any affiliation or just state that you're a happy user.

Comment: No problem, I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: its not FREE when you can only download it if you pay £129 a year subscription